# Skeletal animation interpolation in real-time graphics

Tags: opengl, math, graphics, direct3d, glm-math

Is there a standard interpolation method for interpolation between skeletal animation keyframes? Right now I'm using `glm::slerp()`.

Are there interpolation methods other than slerp and lerp?

According to the [glm docs](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00153.html#gaaea9592fd53952b636d680321edcdb31), `glm::mix(quat1, quat2, a)` does spherical linear interpolation of two quaternions, and `glm::slerp(quat1, quat2, a)` does "short path spherical linear interpolation" of two quaternions. What's the difference?

Comment: Why tag this with Direct3D when it's an OpenGL question?

Comment: Its not an opengl question

Comment: So... both the Direct3D and OpenGL tags are inappropriate, then.

Comment: Its a CG question. It would be a shame if an opengl expert who knows the answer missed this. Maybe Ketlar was searching for opengl tags.

Comment: If it's a cg question, then use the cg tag.  I don't think tag spamming is a good way to draw attention to your question; it dilutes the usefulness of tags in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, [look](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/gtc/quaternion.inl#L559) at source [code](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/gtc/quaternion.inl#L592). The only difference is this part (aside from different x/y/z naming):

```
    // If cosTheta < 0, the interpolation will take the long way around the sphere. 
    // To fix this, one quat must be negated.
    if (cosTheta < T(0))
    {
        z        = -y;
        cosTheta = -cosTheta;
    }
```

Basically they're the same except `slerp` ensures interpolation will take shorter path on the sphere while `mix` don't care and may take opposite longer path.

There are many other interpolation methods; probably most advanced is bezier curve (used my most animation software), but it requires quite a lot more memory and computation power.